# Reading from two textfiles: one array to keep, one array to omit from textfile

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, java.util.scanner

This is the problem:

I'm given a text with certain words and characters that I am to omit. I am to create a method that will return an array of words with two file arguments like this:

```
public Word[] keyWordsList(File inputFile1, File inputFile2)
```

inputFile2 contains a bunch of words and punctuations that I am to ignore from what is contained in inputFile1.

inputFile2 contains the following:

> of the a in on , . ?

inputFile1 contains a whole paragraph of text, and I am to push each of those words into the Word[].

I just need help in understanding how I can accurately place all the words and omit the ones from inputFile2 because inputFile2 contains both string and character primitive types.

This is my code to solve this issue (which has been fairly successful) but I just don't know how to handle the exception where the punctuation is right after the word.

```
    Scanner ignore = new Scanner(inputFile2);
    Scanner important = new Scanner(inputFile1);

    ArrayList<String> ignoreArray = new ArrayList<>();

    while (ignore.hasNext()) {
        String ignoreWord = ignore.next();
        ignoreArray.add(ignoreWord);
    }

    ArrayList<String> importantWords = new ArrayList<>();

    while (important.hasNext()) {
        String word = important.next();
        if (ignoreArray.contains(word))
            continue;
        else
            importantWords.add(word);
    }
```

I'm getting results like this:

[This, is, input, file, to, create, key, words, **list.,** If, we, ever, want, to, know, how, background, job, **works,,** fastest, way, to, find, k, smallest, elements, an, **array,,**] etc.etc.

From this:

> This is the input file to create key words list.
>   If we ever want to know how background job works, fastest way to find k smallest elements in an array,

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Why a PriorityQueue? Priority of what? And *what* PriorityQueue? There isn't one here. All you need is a `Set` of words to omit, and a file scan operation that consults the set to see whether or not to copy each word to the target array.

Comment: First hint: You want to use this method to scan the file: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.lang.String). The parameter is a regular expression that will give you a word or a punctuation character.

Comment: Second hint: consider replacing the `ignoreArray` with a hash map.